# A free simulation program

Tags: 3d-design

With some of the items I am designing I would love to put them through a simulation. Like crushing, for example. I want to know how well my object can handle any situation I put it through so I can make changes before I print out the object, only to find out there was a weak spot.

I have been trying to learn ParaView but it is a little complicated off the bat, I would like something easy to use.

If anybody knows of a program that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fusion 360 will do finite element analysis (simulation), although I haven't used it. Whether it will perform the type of analysis that you are looking for, I do not know. Check Autodesk's tutorials.

One problem that you will encounter is that items printed using FDM technology are highly anisotropic. In other words, they have a grain, and are stronger/weaker in some directions than in others. I do not think that Fusion 360 can take account of that in its analysis.

[Autodesk: Fusion 360](http://help.autodesk.com/view/fusion360/ENU/)

Comment: I couldn't find it while I was on the site, but, how much is fusion 360?

Comment: It is free for educators, students, enthusiasts and start-ups. Just install the free trial and register as an enthusiast once the free-trial period expires.

Comment: I am liking the idea, but will I be limited of features? And I will stop asking questions, thanks for the help!

Comment: No. It's a fully-working version. Autodesk have said that they will keep it free for enthusiasts "for the foreseeable future". The only drawback that I can see is that your work is stored in the cloud. I would much prefer the option to only store my files on my hard drive, but that is not a option.

Comment: Ask as many questions as you like, but not as comments. New questions are preferred,

Comment: The cloud? I am no expert but I would think you can download it from the cloud then. That is all I needed to know about think program. I will give it a try. I am looking forward to seeing what this program has to offer me. Thank you!